# If there are any fully valid/legally accepted digital/electronic signature techniques in the US

Tags: signature, digital-contract

After reading [this](https://www.cryptomathic.com/news-events/blog/us-court-rejects-docusign-e-signatures-as-method-to-provide-digital-authorization) from 2016 "it remains to be seen" if in the US digital/electronic signatures will be acceptable in court as a valid alternative to "wet" signatures.

I'm wondering if this problem has since been resolved, and if there are any standards/protocols/requirements/regulations/techniques/methods for assuring a digital signature is valid in a court of law, for any possible type of document (some sites said things like "wills" must be signed with wet signatures, but maybe this has since changed).